# gcloud app deploy - TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Tags: django, gcloud

This is the first time for me to deploy my app in google cloud. When I enter '`gcloud app deploy`' command, it failed due to `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'`. But it doesn't seem like a problem of my coding but django itself. Please give me any comment which helps me to understand this error message.

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Application startup
error: [2018-08-06 23:53:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-08-06 23:53:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at:
http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1) [2018-08-06 23:53:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using
worker: sync [2018-08-06 23:53:20 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker
with pid: 7 [2018-08-06 23:53:20 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in
worker process Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in
spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()   File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129,
in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()   File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138,
in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()   File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in
wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()   File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52,
in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()   File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41,
in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)   File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in
import_app
    __import__(module)   File "/home/vmagent/app/acct/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()   File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in
get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)   File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in
setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112,
in populate
    app_config.import_models()   File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in
import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/data_wizard/models.py", line 15, in
<module>
    class Run(models.Model):   File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/data_wizard/models.py", line 16, in
Run
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete' [2018-08-06 23:53:20 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
[2018-08-06 23:53:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-08-06 23:53:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Comment: I am not sure whether data-wizard 1.0.1 support django 2 or not, and found that I do not use this module anymore. So I remove this from my coding and it works now. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a problem with `django-data-wizard`. Starting from Django 2.0 `on_delete` argument is mandatory for `ForeignKey` fields and apparently data wizard library is not passing that argument:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0

> The on_delete argument for ForeignKey and OneToOneField is now required in models and migrations.

Check if your version of data wizard supports Django 2.x or remove the dependency if not needed.